# What is the best way of monitoring if monerod is still running on a VPS server?

Tags: monerod, server

I have `monerod` running on my VPS server and would like to know if it ever fails or isn't running. What is the best way to monitor this service and have it alert me on telegram or some other app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways this can be achieved. The simplest is to make use of the daemons RPC interface and call a method like [get_height](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_height) or [get_info](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html#get_info). When you start `monerod`, I'd recommend starting with the `--restricted-rpc` flag (to restrict it to view only commands). Then just configure your firewall to allow inbound connections to port `18081` (or a different port if you changed from the default via `--rpc-bind-port`).

As an alternative to opening up for inbound connections, you could write a cron job   that runs on the same host, which again uses the RPC interface, but emails you if there are issues.